# Recreate Jquery DataTable with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a `<select >` with table names and a button.  Everytime I press the button I have to bring the data from database of the selected table.

The problem is that if I try to bring data from a table with different number of columns than the previous table, it gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined(…)

it's been more than 13hours I'm trying to make this work and nothing yet.

Here is the code where I :

- Try to destroy the datatable if there is one already;
- get the column name from database to create it dinamically on datatable;
- get the data of the selected table from database;
- fill the datatable with data + columns:

  ```
  $('body').on('click', '#btnTeste', function(e){
  if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#myTable') ) {        
    $('#myTable').DataTable().destroy();
  }

  e.preventDefault();
  var tabela = $('select[name=selectTable]').val();

  // Busca nome das columnas da tabela selecionada
  var columns = [];
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'getcolumnName.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {table: tabela},
      success:function(data){            
          for(i=0; i < data.length; i++)
          {
              /*if(tabela == 'localidade')
              {
                  columns.push( { "mDataProp": "Field"+ (i+1), sTitle: data[i].replace("dsc_","").replace("cod_munic", "cidade")
                      .replace("id_bairro", "bairro").replace("id_endereco", "endereco"), sType : "string"} );
              }
              else */
                  columns.push( { "mDataProp": "Field"+ (i+1), sTitle: data[i].replace("dsc_",""), sType : "string"} );
          }
      }
  })
  .done(function(msg){        
      var dados;
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'listaLocalidade.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {table: tabela},
          success:function(data){
              dados = data;
          }
      })
      .done(function(msg){
          var nFields   = Object.keys(dados[0]).length;
          var nElements = dados.length; 

          //Prepara array dos dados            
          var resultado = [];
          for(i=0;  i< nElements; i++){
              resultado[i] = {};
              var prop = "Field";
              for(j=0; j < nFields; j++)
              {
                  resultado[i][prop + (j+1)] = dados[i][ columns[j]['sTitle'] ];
              }                
          }
          console.log(columns);
          console.log(resultado);
          $('#myTable').DataTable({
              "aoColumns" : columns,
              "aaData": resultado
          });
      });
  });
  ```

  });